# How to add a dependency to all linked targets using Bazel's cc_toolchain?

Tags: arm, bazel, bazel-cpp

I've followed the tutorial [here](https://bazel.build/tutorials/ccp-toolchain-config) to create a custom Bazel toolchain that builds and links a binary for a baremetal ARM platform. My binary target currently looks like this:

```
cc_binary(
  name = "hello-world",
  srcs = [
    "hello-world.cpp",
  ],
  linkopts = ["-T", "$(location :FLASH.ld)"],
  deps = [
    "//libc:polyfill",
    ":FLASH.ld",
  ],
)
```

I'm using newlib, so the target `//libc:polyfill` is a static library that contains implementations of some C standard library functions for my platform--e.g., `open()`, `sbrk()`, etc. The definition for that target looks like this:

```
cc_library(
  name = "polyfill",
  srcs = [
    "syscalls.c",
    "sysmem.c",
  ],

  # Causes bazel to always link this library, and wrap it in
  # -Wl,--whole-archive, which is needed to prevent symbol resolution errors
  # related to link order (since this library implements some C standard
  # library functions). See:
  # https://bazel.build/reference/be/c-cpp#cc_library
  alwayslink = True,
)
```

I would like my toolchain to automatically add `//libc:polyfill` as a dependency for all linked targets using my toolchain. [The Toolchains page](https://bazel.build/extending/toolchains#writing-rules-toolchains) provides an example using a totally custom rule, but I want to leverage `cc_toolchain` if possible. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never found a good way of doing that with a Bazel rule. The best way I've found is compiling your library separately and then adding it to the appropriate sets of linker flags. You'll also need to add it to `cc_toolchain.linker_files` (or one of the other attributes) so your library is an input to the appropriate linking actions. You can use `genrule` to compile the library, but `cc_library` is awkward because you need a separate toolchain to avoid circular dependencies.

The less-good way I've done this is by abusing [--custom_malloc](https://bazel.build/reference/command-line-reference#flag--custom_malloc). You can set it to a library that uses `select` to add a dependency on your desired library for targets using this particular toolchain (`--custom_malloc` applies to all targets, including host ones, so you do need the `select`). You also have to use `malloc = None` on those libraries to avoid circular dependencies. I've used this approach before, but it gets kind of annoying when you start using query/cquery, and it's pretty bad for caching.